# codeigniter accesing object value in input element value getting Error

Tags: codeigniter

[image]

In codeigniter:
I found the data in object form in this page but when i assign value to particular input element it returning me the error. give me the solution

Output screen is given below:
[image]

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While fetching data from database please use

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$ret = $query->row();
```

In your code you are getting array, that's the reason you are getting error.

Let me know if you have another error.

Please change your line like given below.

```
<?php
echo form_input(array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name','value'=>$value->name)); 
?>
```

Comment: i used this --><?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name','value'=>"<php echo $value->name;?>")); ?>   to get value warning reolved but input box showing php syntax as well as like returning <php echo Gaurav1;?>  on the html input box

Comment: Chaek my answer and let me know if you have any error

Comment: @Gaurav : Glad to help out from this hurdles.

Comment: one more thing can i get this values on update case when i ve a update function   ublic function update($id){
  
  $this->load->model('latest_model');
  $val=$this->latest_model->id_data($id);
    $data['value']=$val;
         //echo "<pre>";print_r($val);

    $name=$this->input->post('name');
    echo $name;
   $this->load->view('new_login',$data);    not getting name value

Comment: Can you please add your issue in your question, So I can understand what another error you have.

Comment: It seems like you have error in your model function `$val = $this->latest_model->id_data($id);` here. What you want to do here.?

Comment: i want to update records using model and controller but from the last 2 day m stuck here note getting proper result from google in eaisest way.. can u please help

Answer (score 0):

Please find your code for update.

```
public function update($id) {
    $this->load->model('latest_model');

    $upd_data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $val = $this->db->update('table_name', $upd_data);

    $data['value'] = $val;
    $this->load->view('new_login', $data);
}
```

For redirect to another page

```
$this->load->helper('url');
redirect('controllerName/methodName');
```

Example

```
redirect('user/dashboard');
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: Not working ...  getting error Call to undefined method Latest_model::update() in /var/www/html/CI2/application/controllers/latest_ctrl.php on line 53, referer: http://newci.com/latest_ctrl/view

Comment: not working shyam bhai ... can i get your mail id i ll send the file to u  cos i am a newbie in codeigniter

Comment: one problem is there after submit or insert i want to redirect this page to another page is it possible ??

Comment: <td><?php  echo $row->email; ?></td> but i m not getting this email value it reurns the error how can we use ternery operater here .. describe this to me pls

Comment: You can use `<?= (isset($row->email) ? $row->email : 'Email not available'; ?>`

Comment: not working geting error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$email

Filename: views/task1.php

Line Number: 23

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146819/discussion-between-shyam-shingadiya-and-gaurav).